# How do I get best 'score' coefs instead of best 'estimator'?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I have created my own estimator that wraps a sklearn regressor.

```
GSV = GridSearchCV(pipe,
                       param_grid = {'step2':[1,2,3]},
                       cv=splits,
                       verbose=1
                       )

GSV.fit(X, y)
```

I usually look at :

```
GSV.best_estimator_.named_steps['step2'].coef_
```

To get best coefs.

However, I may score an estimator result to zero in the 'score' override. This appears to be applied after best.estimator has been set - how can I get coefs for my best score?

Comment: What is a "'score' override, and how does it affect the model-fit/search/selection?

Comment: The score is a part of the standard sklearn package that allows you to create your own scoring (instead os MSE say)

Comment: You mean grid search's `scoring` parameter? Why would that be set to zero? Scoring happens before selecting and refitting the `best_estimator_`.